# Why is this giving me "Undefined references to constructors and destructors"?

Tags: c++

I have the following pieces of code:

Leomedia.h

```
#include "MusicMetaDatter.h"

#ifndef LEOMEDIA_H
#define LEOMEDIA_H

namespace Leomedia
{
    typedef enum
    {
        read,
        write
    } FileMode;
}

#endif // LEOMEDIA_H
```

MusicMetaDatter.h

```
#ifndef MUSICMETADATTER_H
#define MUSICMETADATTER_H

#include "Leomedia.h"
#include <string>

/**
* METADATTER
* @Version 1.0.0a
* @Author: Sergio Andrés Ibañez (Leonnears)
* @Twitter: Leonnears
* @Package: Leomedia
*/

    namespace Leomedia
    {
        typedef enum
        {
            mp3,
            m4a,
            flac,
            ape,
            wavPack,
            aiff,
            wav,
            ogg,
            tta
        } AudioFileType;

        class MusicMetaDatter
        {
            public:
                MusicMetaDatter(std::string fileName, AudioFileType type, FileMode mode);
                virtual ~MusicMetaDatter();

            private:
                std::string md_fileName;
                AudioFileType md_fileType;
                FileMode md_fileMode;
        };
    }

    #endif // MUSICMETADATTER_H
```

MusicMetaDatter.cpp

```
#include "MusicMetaDatter.h"
#include <string>

Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::MusicMetaDatter(std::string fileName, AudioFileType type, FileMode mode)
{
    this -> md_fileName = fileName;
    this -> md_fileType = type;
    this -> md_fileMode = mode;
}

Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::~MusicMetaDatter()
{
    //dtor
}
```

MetaDatterTest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Leomedia.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter meta("troll", Leomedia::mp3, Leomedia::read);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile MetaDatterTest I get the following errors:

undefined reference to Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::MusicMetaDatter(std::string, Leomedia::AudioFileType, Leomedia::FileMode)'
undefined reference to Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::~MusicMetaDatter()'
undefined reference to Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::~MusicMetaDatter()'

All the files are in the same directory. I'm using mingw 4.4.1

Can someone help me with this? It has dumbfounded me beyond understanding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't given your compile command, but I suspect it lacks `MusicMetaDatter.cpp` in it.

Should be something like

```
g++ -o MetaDatterTest MetaDatterTest.cpp MusicMetaDatter.cpp
```

Comment: I compile by pressing F9 directly with Code::Blocks. How do I check what command is it executing exactly?

Comment: No idea, perhaps you need to make sure both files are added to the project? I have never used it...

Comment: Yep, that was it. I wasn't working with them on a project, but I made a project, added them there, and solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Those are linker errors. It compiled just fine. When you link it, you'll need to link to the code that contains the destructor for `MusicMetaDatter` or you'll get that error.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not compilation error, they are linkers error. It is probably because you've done this:

```
g++ MetaDatterTest.cpp
```

instead of this,

```
g++ MetaDatterTest.cpp MusicMetaDatter.cpp
```

Try this!

---

Now I will comment on your coding style:

```
Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter::MusicMetaDatter(std::string fileName, AudioFileType type, FileMode mode)
{
    this -> md_fileName = fileName;
    this -> md_fileType = type;
    this -> md_fileMode = mode;
}
```

This is bad style. `Leomedia` is a namespace, so you've written  `Leomedia::MusicMetaDatter`, but you have not written `Leomedia::AudioFileType` and `Leomedia::FileMode` in the parameter list.

The better coding-style is this:

```
namespace Leomedia
{
   MusicMetaDatter::MusicMetaDatter(std::string fileName, AudioFileType type, FileMode mode)
   {
      this -> md_fileName = fileName;
      this -> md_fileType = type;
      this -> md_fileMode = mode;
   }
}
```

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but does it deal with immediate problem?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: No, and I've said that as well.

Comment: All for the best. I have changed it to your suggestion. I will look at the compilation commands now. Thanks for your input.